# Batch Renaming All Files in a Folder

Tags: batch-file, rename

I'm having trouble understanding this batch code, what exactly does it do? Rename all the .doc files in the 'folderName' folder?

```
ren folderName\.*docc *.doc
```

Comment: The . and star need to be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

The command you've posted means:

from the current directory, find the subdirectory folderName

Within that directory, find all filenames ".*docc" ie. starting with `.` followed by any number of any characters and ending with `docc`

rename then to - well, frankly I don't know for sure. Probably (the part other than `docc`) + `.doc` It's such an unusual command and `ren` is known to react bizarrely when `*` is used where the filename-length changes, I'd not try it.

Probably, as noted in comments, the command should have been

```
ren folderName\*.docc *.doc
```

which should mean:

from the current directory, find the subdirectory folderName

Within that directory, find all filenames "*.docc" ie. starting with any number of any characters and ending with `docc`

Rename those such that they end with `.doc` instead.